# How can I read a "drive label" or "volume name" in .NET?

Tags: .net, wmi

Can you show sample code for reading a drive label or volume name in .NET? I get the sense this requires WMI, but I am loathe to "drop-down" into WMI because it is like dropping down into a string-based SQL query in the sense that certain objects may not exist on certain versions of OSes or the user may not have the right to query certain data. I will be happy to be convinced that I'm wrong about WMI ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No WMI required. The following will get all volume labels:

```
var labels = from drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
             select drive.VolumeLabel
```

Comment: Or just (new DriveInfo("C")).VolumeLabel

Comment: This is the correct answer. I find it is better to get a DriveInfo instance and then ask for the VolumeLabel as a separate statement because drive.VolumeLabel throws an IOException when "the drive is not ready", such as an empty CDROM. Any tips on how to avoid this exception? Just swallow it?

Answer (score 3):

Call DriveInfo.GetDrives to get an array of drive information. Then look at DriveInfo.VolumeLabel

Answer (score 1):

You could use System.IO.DriveInfo to get the list of drives. See following example:

Note: CDRom drive types do not have a volume name.

```
Using System.IO;
.
.
.
DriveInfo[] driveInfoList = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo drive in driveInfoList)
{
    if (drive.DriveType != DriveType.CDRom)
       textBox1.Text += String.Format("Name:{0} Volume:{1}\r\n", drive.Name, drive.VolumeLabel);
    else
       textBox1.Text += String.Format("Name:{0}\r\n", drive.
}
```

Comment: CDROM and other removable drives have labels when they contain disks with labels.

Comment: I guess the best way to avoid errors is to test driveInfo.IsReady before asking for the VolumeLabel.